# PostgreSQL: After using CreateLang, I still get an error "42704: language "plpgsql" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

I am using pgProvider on a MVC3 Mono application and had no issues on Windows Postgres 9.2. I am migrating to my production Linux/Mono environment, and received an error when attempting to access the provider:

```
"42704: language "plpgsql" does not exist"
```

I am using postgreSQL 8.4 on CentOS 6.3

I looked at some info, and ran the following:

```
createlang -d dbname plpgsql
```

When I run it again, it affirms that the database is already there.

I restarted postgresql and my app. However, I still get the above error.

Does anyone have any info on why I would still receive an "plpgsql does not exist -- after it is installed?"

Comment: Are you sure that you're accessing the correct database with the application?  Maybe it's connecting to some other database.

Comment: It must be. When I revisit this I am sure it will become foolish and obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this sort of error is an indication that something is not as you expect and you need to challenge your assumptions.

Please note that languages do *not* require restarting the database server to take effect on any version of PostgreSQL.  Also note that what languages are allowed in PostgreSQL is a per-db catalog entry (languages, unlike users and roles, are not cluster-global).

So in troubleshooting this, you need to start with:

1. Is this the right db?  The right server?
2. Is my application connecting to the same db/server I think it is?

Given that createlang affirms that the language exists after you run it, this can't be an issue with PostgreSQL raising a phony error.  Instead it must be a problem with the changes you made not affecting the database your application is using.

Comment: I agree with the "something is not as I expect". I'll be damned if I can figure out what, however!